# How do I check the filesystem type of a device?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext3, xfs

I formatted a partition using `mkfs.xfs /dev/mydevice` in Ubuntu and then I mounted it using `/etc/fstab`. When I type `mount`, it tells me that my device is mounted as ext3.

Output of `mount`:

```
/dev/mydevice on /mnt/mymount type ext3 (rw,_netdev)
```

First question: How do I know if it's xfs or ext3? What am I missing?

Second question: If it's xfs, how do I know if it's xfs-256 or xfs-512?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loading the device in a utility like gparted tells you FS types.
for fstab file it's enough, I think, to say only xfs.